# Editing twice while reviewing throws me out of the reviewing interface

Tags: bug, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

Since I've encountered this several times, I think the issue is reproducible, although I'm not 100% sure. The issue is: When I'm reviewing (first posts) and edit a question/answer, after applying changes, I'm back to the review interface (and can click "I'm done"). However, when I notice that something needs more improvement and I edit for the second time, applying the second edit throws me out of the review interface to the question page.

PS there's another similar bug: when one edits a post which happened to be a high-quality post that was given as a test to the reviewer ("first answer" in my case), after editing the reviewer ends up on the question page instead of on the reviewing page/interface.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259597/294055

Comment: @honk thanks. I'm not sure if this is to be closed though: the bug report you mentioned migrated from meta.SO there - and that's why I haven't found it when I was searching for such questions here. May be such a duplicate deserves being kept here as well, with your helpful link.

Comment: I'm the user who issued the other bug report here on MSO. I'm also the user who asked for its migration to MSE, because another user was able to reproduce the problem on other sites, too. Anyway, even that didn't cause a developer to fix that bug. Therefore I appreciate your report here, because it shows that I'm not the only user that got annoyed by this bug ;)

Comment: Anyway, as I have now more than 2k rep, I no longer encounter this bug.

Comment: @honk why it that? You have other interface of reviewing? Or is it just because you don't need a review by others to get an edit applied?

Comment: The latter one. If you reach 2k, then you can edit posts without review. As far as I remember, I haven't encountered the bug since then...

Comment: I agree that this is a bug that should be fixed.